# Adding shadow under the element using ::before

Tags: html, css

I need to add a shadow png repeated under a li on hover, for a "nicer" effect, but I am still getting the shadow showing over the li, even if I give it a z-index of negative, or lower then the li itself.

CSS:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:hover {
    z-index:300;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:hover > a::after {
    content: "";
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../img/shadow.png") repeat scroll 0 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left: 7px;
    top: 7px;
    z-index: -1000;
}
```

You can see the live website here: http://florin-pop.com/work/Visa%20Menu/index.html

I tried everything I could imagine but couldn't find a solution.

Florin

Comment: Pseudo elements are created _inside_ the element not actually _after/before_ the element so your `z-index` will not have the effect you think it will. Move the `::after` to the `li` instead of the `a` and it will work

Comment: Thank you :) Please add your answer so anyone can see it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code generates a pseudo element here...

```
<li>
    <a>
        [textNode]
        ::after /* here is your pseudo element */
    </a>
</li>
```

you can't use `z-index` to force an element behind the element that forms the base of the current stacking context. In this case your `<a>` (`.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a { z-index: 3; }`).

I would suggest that it would be better to generate your element here...

```
<li>
    ::before /* here is your pseudo element */
    <a>
        [textNode]
    </a>
</li>
```

This would remove the need to use `z-index` entirely as the pseudo element is generated *before* the child element(`<a>`).

Changing your CSS to the following should work...

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:hover::before {
   ...
}
```

Comment: You **can** use `z-index` to place an element behind its ancestors if they don't establish any stacking context.